Is there a "dark mode" setting for Super User?
I love "dark mode" on Stack Overflow and prefer using it everywhere.
I cannot find the setting, and I've tried looking everywhere in the settings.
Does Super User have a Dark Mode? If so, how do I enable it?

No, there is not. and the stackoverflow dark mode has serious issues, so perhaps stack exchange is using overflow as a test. They got some work to do yet

https://meta.superuser.com/search?q=dark

I guess this is a touchy subject. This is getting down voted.

It may be getting downvoted because there are a variety of questions regarding this and a quick search would have shown that. Perceived lack of effort is a big reason for downvotes, in my experience.

The html served from Stack Overflow versus other sites differs by a few lines. There has been available a MonkeyScript that supposedly worked on Stack Overflow prior to dark being enabled for all users ( https://gist.sharingeye.com/patrickroberts/b0c62bddd710f3a3dca5f1d2cadfd678 ) but it currently doesn't add an upper right button for quick toggling, probably due to changes to the site's html since it was written; though I suspect that it could be edited and fixed to work everywhere. See https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/31/building-dark-mode-on-stack-overflow/ it's more than a simple change.

There isn't one.
While in theory stacks (the design/theming engine behind modern SE) supports themes, the resources and will to develop alternate themes outside of Stack Overflow isn't there.
There's also historically been a backlog of sites with no theme, that the company has been working through over time.
Practically, I'd love the idea of a dark theme too but its unlikely to happen any time soon

It's simple CSS. How can I help?

Heh, if it was as simple as pitching in what's needed we'd have a ton done by now

How do we make progress?

Some days I wish I knew. I have a pretty big list of things I'd like to see, and that's somewhere around the middle.

There's no, as of 2024-11, but just in case, there's an extension for the most common modern browsers - Dark Reader.
It should work out-of-the-box for the current version of both main and meta versions of Super User.
It should also work for the most Stack Exchange and various other websites out there with conventional/expected or not too complex stylesheet the extension's multiple algorithms can handle. If those does not result in anything desired, it sure features custom stylesheets to override or append.
By default, currently, it affects (namely "inverts") every website possible
or as with a set deny-list, but there's an option to set it to affect only the chosen (i.e. allow-list) - "Invert listed only".
Example



Main
Meta









